# Libclang returning incorrect cursor types (stdlib and namespaced types)

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-clang, libclang

I am using libclang to do some basic reflection of C++. I am creating a translation unit for a header and then visiting all the tree elements using the cursors, in some cases I fall back onto the qualtypes to get the necessary information out. The problem is right now that the cursor types libclang returns are incorrect. For the example header file below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    struct B
    {
        std::string m_string;
        std::vector<float> m_vector;
    };
}
```

I parse it using **clang_parseTranslationUnit2** with the following inputs:

**Args:**
"-x", "c++"

**Options:**
CXTranslationUnit_DetailedPreprocessingRecord | CXTranslationUnit_SkipFunctionBodies | CXTranslationUnit_Incomplete;

Now when visiting the fields for struct B I get:

**CXType_Int** for the cursor to m_vector instead of **CXtype_Unexposed**

but for the **std::string** member m_string, I get **CXType_Unexposed** which allows me to visit the field and extract the necessary info. When visiting the field for the string I correctly get the "namespace" then "typeref" cursor types.

I am completely out of ideas as to what is going on, why does lib clang fail to understand the std::vector type?

I got latest on the libclang version on June 1st, 2015.

Comment: did you find a solution this?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: I dont have the issue with later versions of clang.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66702426

Basically, the default type for anything in libclang is apparently int. If there is a parsing failure you could see types show up as int instead of their proper types. Check for diagnostics after parsing and fail if there are any, instead of going on and printing bad types.

Answer (score -1):

try add clang headers dir in compile flags